# How to fetch only some of the rows in .csv file while executing Coded UI parameterised Tests

Tags: unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

I am using coded UI to run tests which take values from .csv which is added as the datasource but I require first few rows for one TestMethod  and then next few rows for another Test method so is there a way to define the range of rows to be fetched for TestMethod as this will reduce the number of .csv files required to create. Please suggest the approach

Comment: You could check the data row number and build an if statement around it

Answer (score 0):

You could have one test method that reads the one CSV file. Add another column into the CSV file (perhaps it could be titled "TestToBeRun") and use that to select the test to execute. So the code looks similar to:

```
[TestMethod, DataSource(...csv...)]
public void MyBigTestMethod()
{
    string testToRun = TestContext.DataRow["TestToBeRun"].ToString();
    switch ( testToRun )
    {
    case "AAA" : TestMethodAAA(); break;
    case "BBB" : TestMethodBBB(); break;
    case "CCC" : TestMethodCCC(); break;
    ... // and so on
    default: Assert.Fail("Test case not recognised: '" +  testToRun + "'"); break;
    }
}
```

Of course the problem with this is that there is now only one test name as far as Coded UI is concerned.